# Spartan-3E Starter Kit: Unable to understand required Voltage and Current ratings

Tags: power-supply, fpga

I am talking about [this](http://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/HW-SPAR3E-SK-US-G.htm) kit from xilinx. I am trying to know its input power requirements. The page I have linked just talk about main AC power and not the required DC voltage and current. I saw on the board just below the power socket "5 VDC Only". Now the problem is I am having many power adapters with 5 VDC , but they all have varying amount of currents. So I just want to know:

1- What should be the current rating for the safe operation.

2- Do I really bother about the current rating (since the board only mentions 5 VDC, and nothing about the current).

Comment: Start with the highest rated adapter you have.

Comment: Current ratings on supplies are upper limits on what the supply can provide. The load (your dev board) will take only the current it needs. If you try using a supply with a current rating that is too low, the board will still demand the current it wants, and overwhelm the supply. Chances are high the supply voltage will droop, probably not good for your board, and that the supply will get very very hot. As Thorn said, use the biggest one (with the correct voltage) that you have.

Comment: "Do I really bother about the current rating" Absolutely, there are some minimum requirements for the board that you must meet. Voltage 5VDC is one, the minimum power is another one, I believe for the board you mention the minimum requirement is 2A. The board will operate with a 5V-1A supply but only with a very small project.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you meet the minimum current rating you will be fine (you can't "overcurrent" by using a supply with a higher rating). I'd look for a 2 amp supply.

Note that the HW-SPAR3E-SK-UNI-G is [discontinued](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/customer_notices/xcn12019.pdf) in favor of the [EK-S6-SP601-G](http://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/EK-S6-SP601-G.htm)

Comment: why you would look for 2 amp supply?

Comment: fwiw, the supply included in the kit when I got one of these was rated 3A